# How do I read a block from a specific replica in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I need to write a program for pulling out blocks in HDFS **from a specific data node** for a given file. This is not run within a `MapReduce` job, but pro grammatically for gathering some statistics on my cluster.

So far, given a file, I have been able to extract the Block Locations associated with that file. For each block there are multiple replicas and I need to access blocks lying on a certain replica. I understand these will mostly be remote read operations.

I have done the following:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
Path inFile = new Path(args[0]);
FileStatus status = fs.getFileStatus(inFile);
BlockLocation[] locs = fs.getFileBlockLocations(status, 0, status.getLen());
String[] hosts = locs[0].getHosts ();
```

Could someone tell me how I can fetch the block pointed by *locs[0]* from *hosts[0]*?

Comment: what is the use case of the above requirement?